# Xcode/Fastlane Environment Variables not present after archive

Tags: ios, swift, environment-variables, target, fastlane

We have to set different values for some properties based on the schema and it works properly when we are building from Xcode directly (which is expected behaviour) but setting env variables from Fastfile like in the example below leads us to the build without values for env variables.

```
build_app(scheme: "SCHEMA_NAME", xcargs: "TOKEN='#{ENV["TOKEN"]}'")
```

What's the best practice for saving different values for env variables outside of source code.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do that is using .env files, please see more details here

- Visit https://docs.fastlane.tools/faqs/
- Scroll down
- Follow **Multiple targets of the same underlying app**

Please feel free to open discussion here, if you need more help
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions/categories/q-a